# Estimate the spatial relationship between two sets of points

Tags: r, point

I have two sets of point data, structured like below.

```
Table A 
long | lat | class 
 ... | ... | A
 ... | ... | A
 ... | ... | A

Table B
long | lat | class 
 ... | ... | B
 ... | ... | B
 ... | ... | B
```

Both tables aim to capture locations of the same certain things, but Table B is much more granular than Table A. The result is that Table B is quite large (higher n) and Table A is more manageable.

I want to see if Table A is representative of Table B (in other words, is Table A "good enough" to represent table B?). How might I approach this? My thought was to see if they two classes are spatially correlated for a certain geography, but I don't know how I would approach this. I'm using R.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic "point pattern analysis" problem. Your hypothesis is something like both sets of points come from the same underlying intensity process, or that table A is a random subset of tables A + B.

Various tests exist for testing hypotheses like this, mostly implemented in the `spatstat` package. Textbooks by Baddeley et al or Diggle or Cressie are good references.

Another option is the `spatialkernel` package which can show where on a map the intensity of pattern A is significantly higher than pattern B - for example to show areas of significantly high crime taking into account diversity in population density.